# How to link external server to MS Acess

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2016

Currently I'm using external server linkage in Excel from External data connection(SQL server analysis services (SSAS cube)) and reporting the data using different pivot tables and macros. As this is slower, thinking to move it to Access database for faster execution using SQL queries. But I don't understand how to link external server data to MS Access?

In Excel, I follow the following routine,

Data -> Connections -> Add connection

In MS Access(2016), I'm unable to find the solution for this scenario, please let me know if there is a way in Access to connect SSAS cube. Any help is appreciated, thanks!
(I can see external data tab in access but it has mostly local file import options, but couldn't figure out a way for linking the external server to yield the data from there)

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: What platform are you attempting to connect Access to? What is the external server? We need more information to help.

Comment: you are telling us you can't see "ODBC DATABASE" option in the [External data] tab?

Comment: @ Christopher D: updated post, @krishKM : I can see this feature, it only has file type database import option, I'm looking for connection string type option via network.

Comment: its not file type. you can either open "machine data source" your odbc/dns records or you could save your connectionstring into a file.dns and open it. You still haven't specified your question, what server? have you googled about external data-source in access?

Comment: on the external data tab, choose odbc, and you are given TWO options, one to import and the other to link - you want to use the link table option.

Comment: @krishKM Sorry for the late response, MS SQL server analysis services. I tried opening, by pasting connection string in dns file, but it doesn't work that way